# Profiling performance of IBM DB2 9.7 triggers

Tags: triggers, db2

Is there an easy way to profile the performance of DB2 9.7 Update/Insert/Delete triggers? I have a situation where when I execute a trigger with a set of parameters, it takes 1s to complete. When I execute it a second time with same parameters, execution drops to 10ms. If I execute the same trigger with some other parameters, it again takes 1s. So apparently there is some caching. However, the statement structure is still the same so in my opinnion it shouldn't need to build anything from scratch.

I would now need to profile the triggers to see where the execution time is actually spent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanks AngocA for your answer. A trigger inserts a new set of rows to
>   another table. In subsequent runs, the same amount of rows triggered
>   and added. That is why I am slightly confused regarding why the first
>   run is slow, but the next exactly the same run is 10 times faster.

It has something to do with loading the tables. An DBMS usually does not have all tables (or all data of a table) in memory. Databases store data on pages. Each page can (and should) contain more than one row. When you add a row, it will be added to a table which is usually (not completely sure if I should have written always here) sorted by the primary key of the table. So depending on the rows you want to add to a table a different page needs to be written to. If it is not loaded yet, it needs to be loaded first and that costs time. The next time you need to write a similar row, it is likely to be placed on the same page.

If a page is full it needs to be split, to ensure that the new record can be written in the right place. So depending on the data different work needs to be done by the database. However, in all cases, the data needs to be persisted to the database immediately. So you always need to wait for the write to finish.

As you see there might be some cashing involved. Which is normal for a database.

As to your original question; have a look at the sql of the trigger to find out what the access paths are.

Comment: is there any graphical interface for this? I know DBAs love text based tools but I like graphs :)

Comment: We use DBI software for our monitoring and performance tuning. However, it is proprietary. Since I am not an DBA, I am not familiar on how the specifics for monitoring triggers.

Answer (score 0):

It depens what the trigger do. For example, if with a set of parameters, it just need toupdate one row, but if with another set of parameteres it should update one million rows, then the performance is not the same.

There is not caching for triggers, all transactions al written directly to transaction logs. That is the reason you should analyze the access plan of the queries used in the trigger. You should also analyze the IO, and other related elements to discover what is happening with your different sets.

Do not forget to update statistics, and why not, perform a reorg on the involved tables.

Comment: Thanks AngocA for your answer. A trigger inserts a new set of rows to another table. In subsequent runs, the same amount of rows triggered and added. That is why I am slightly confused regarding why the first run is slow, but the next exactly the same run is 10 times faster.